# Firebase reset password in firebase dashboard

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase to manage database in my ionic framework. After doing a proper configuration for **Reset Password** in firebase dashboard, still our user are not getting reset password link through mail when they forgot password.

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Most often when this happens, the mail ends up in a spam filter. You can often test by sending a password reset to an account that you own and seeing if you get it.

Comment: Yes, I already tested with my mail and I didn't receive mail. Its not there in Spam folder also. Any help on this?

Comment: I just quickly tested and got the reset password email within a minute. If you're not getting any error messages from your code, the email is likely getting caught somewhere between the Firebase servers and your mailbox.

Comment: Can you please share the reset password configuration in Firebase?

Comment: How are you doing the password reset in the Login & Auth tab of your dashboard? I tried it using the default configuration and was able to get the reset email at an address I own.

Comment: Please find this link : http://prntscr.com/9x635a . In that I have attached ny dash board configuration.  Can you please check & let me know.